# Sorting two lines by field in first line then length of the second line

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I would like to filter a file which has this format:

```
Name1|Name2|Name3  
ACGRTIDKEBDIVNRDIVFDOCDDIC  
Name4|Name5|Name6  
AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP  
Name1|Name7|Name3 
AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ
```

Output

```
Name1|Name7|Name3  
AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ  
Name1|Name2|Name3  
ACGRTIDKEBDIVNRDIVFDOCDDIC  
Name4|Name5|Name6  
AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP
```

I sort the file by the first Name and by keeping the line 1 and 2 together; but I want also to keep only the one with the longest second line (here lien 1 and 2 and remove line 3 and 4).

I was able to sort by Name using awk:

```
awk '{if ((NR%1-2)==0) {line=sprintf("%-30s", $0)} else {print line ":" $0}}' file | sort -t '|' -k1 | tr ':' '\n' > newfile
```

I don't know how to also sort (keep only) by the length of the second line (using sort -n)?

Thanks

Comment: Please wrap your samples in CODE TAGS by editing your question and be more clear in your question too.

Comment: Also if you are sorting your file by column 1 and column 2 then how come `Name7` came in first row, please explain it.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: yes, I would like to keep only for the longest line with the one before (so line 1 and 2 in my example) if there is multiples couples of lines with identical Name (first one before the |).

Comment: The file has around 200000 lines

Comment: Am I reading your comments correctly that the "Output" you show in your question is actually **not** the output you want to get? If so - fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %by_length;
my ($id, $l1);

while (<>) {
    ( sub { $by_length{$id} = {l1 => $l1, l2 => $_}
                if length > length($by_length{$id}{l2} // "")
      },
      sub { $id = (split /\|/)[0]; $l1 = $_ }
    )[$. % 2]->()
}
print @{ $by_length{$_} }{qw{ l1 l2 }} for sort keys %by_length;
```

The hash `%by_length` stores the longest line for each name in its `l2` subkey, together with the corresponding first line under `l1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried and work well (and super fast).

Answer (score 1):

Complex **`awk`** + **`sort`** solution:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0{ sub(/\|/, " ", r); print length, r, $0 }{ r = $0 }' file \
| sort -k2,2 -k1,1nr | awk '{ print $2"|"$3 ORS $NF }'
```

The output:

```
Name1|Name7|Name3
AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ
Name1|Name2|Name3
ACGRTIDKEBDIVNRDIVFDOCDDIC
Name4|Name5|Name6
AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP
```

---

*Bonus* solution (for additional requirement):

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0{ sub(/\|/, " ", r); print length, r, $0 }{ r = $0 }' file \
| sort -k2,2 -k1,1nr | awk '!a[$2]++{ print $2"|"$3 ORS $NF }'
```

The output:

```
Name1|Name7|Name3
AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ
Name4|Name5|Name6
AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP
```

Comment: Nice too. Is it possible to add in the pipeline maybe a if to print only the longest line (with the previous line) using also awk?

Comment: @Nico64, I can't understand your phrase "maybe a if to print only the longest line (with the previous line) "

Comment: If I want to have only in the output line 1 and 2 because line 2 is longer than line 4, then 5 and 6. Can we add a 'if statement' about length and print only line 1 and 2?

Comment: @Nico64, use my "bonus" solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to trivially and portably do what you want without having to store the whole file in memory:

1) Collapse each pair of lines into 1 and prepend the keys you want to sort on:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR%2{n=$1; h=$0; next} {print n, length(), h, $0}' file
Name1 28 Name1|Name2|Name3   ACGRTIDKEBDIVNRDIVFDOCDDIC
Name4 52 Name4|Name5|Name6   AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP
Name1 37 Name1|Name7|Name3  AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ
```

2) sort the above output in whatever order you like:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR%2{n=$1; h=$0; next} {print n, length(), h, $0}' file |
    sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr
Name1 37 Name1|Name7|Name3  AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ
Name1 28 Name1|Name2|Name3   ACGRTIDKEBDIVNRDIVFDOCDDIC
Name4 52 Name4|Name5|Name6   AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP
```

3) Keep just the first occurrence of each primary key value:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR%2{n=$1; h=$0; next} {print n, length(), h, $0}' file |
    sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr |
    awk '!seen[$1]++'
Name1 37 Name1|Name7|Name3  AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ
Name4 52 Name4|Name5|Name6   AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP
```

4) Remove the extra fields added in step 1, resplit into 2-line pars, and print the result:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR%2{n=$1; h=$0; next} {print n, length(), h, $0}' file |
    sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr |
    awk '!seen[$1]++{print $3 ORS $4}'
Name1|Name7|Name3
AGRQHUOQGRINQJIOPQPJGREQPJIRPEQJIRPEQ
Name4|Name5|Name6
AFFHJORJOVFDANJFOONKFANIFNIPNIPNFIPNKFPDNBKFPNBKFP
```

If a blank char doesn't work for you as the separator for the combined fields then just pick a different character that does (e.g. a tab or control character or ...).